# Function pointer as an argument

Tags: c, function-pointers, argument-passing

Is it possible to pass a function pointer as an argument to a function in C?

If so, how would I declare and define a function which takes a function pointer as an argument?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Definitely.

```
void f(void (*a)()) {
    a();
}

void test() {
    printf("hello world\n");
}

int main() {
     f(&test);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Both will work. The ampersand is optional. So is dereferencing the pointer when you're calling the function pointer.

Comment: True, there's no need to change anything. Moreover, even the "pointer" syntax in parameter declaration is optional. The above `f` could've been declared as `void f(void a())`.

Comment: Using a typedef for the function pointer type could make the code eaiser to read.

Comment: Is there a way to have a pointer to a function with pre defined value of one of the inputs? Let's say we have `void f( float * data, float funParam)`. Can we have a pointer to the function with a certain value of `funParam`?

Comment: @Royi no. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393716/is-there-a-a-way-to-achieve-closures-in-c

Answer (score 34):

Let's say that you have a function:

```
int func(int a, float b);
```

So the pointer to it will be:

```
int (*func_pointer)(int, float);
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```
  func_pointer = func;
  (*func_pointer)(1, 1.0);

  /*below also works*/
  func_pointer(1, 1.0);
```

To avoid specifying the full pointer type every time you need it you coud `typedef` it:

```
typedef int (*FUNC_PTR)(int, float);
```

And then use it like any other type:

```
void executor(FUNC_PTR func)
{ 
   func(1, 1.0);
}

int silly_func(int a, float b)
{ 
  //do some stuff
}

main()
{
  FUNC_PTR ptr;
  ptr = silly_func;
  executor(ptr); 
  /* this should also wotk */
  executor(silly_func)
}
```

I suggest looking at the world-famous [C faqs](https://c-faq.com/questions.html).

Answer (score 18):

This is a good example :

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
   return a + b;
}

int mul(int a, int b)
{
   return a * b;
}

int div(int a, int b)
{
   return a / b;
}

int mathOp(int (*OpType)(int, int), int a, int b)
{
   return OpType(a, b);
}

int main()
{

   printf("%i,%i", mathOp(sum, 10, 12), mathOp(div, 10, 2));
   return 0;
}
```

> ```
> The output is : '22, 5'
> ```

Answer (score 3):

As said by other answers, you can do it as in

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

However, there is one special case for declaring an argument of function pointer type: if an argument has the function type, it will be converted to a pointer to the function type, just like arrays are converted to pointers in parameter lists, so the former can also be written as

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int compar(const void *, const void *));
```

Naturally this applies to only parameters, as outside a parameter list `int compar(const void *, const void *);` would declare a function.

Comment: +1 for the very undermentioned readability-improving trick of taking advantage of implicit pointer conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Check `qsort()`

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

The last argument to the function is a function pointer. When you call `qsort()` in a program of yours, the execution "goes into the library" and "steps back into your own code" through the use of that pointer.