# Is there a a way to achieve closures in C

Tags: c, closures

I would like this to work, but it does not:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct closure_s {
  void (*incrementer) ();
  void (*emitter) ();
} closure;

closure emit(int in) {

  void incrementer() {
    in++;
  }

  void emitter() {
    printf("%d\n", in);
  }

  return (closure) {
    incrementer,
    emitter
  };
}

main() {
  closure test[] = {
    emit(10),
    emit(20)
  };

  test[0] . incrementer();
  test[1] . incrementer();

  test[0] . emitter();
  test[1] . emitter();
}
```

It actually *does* compile and does work for 1 instance ... but the second one fails.  Any idea how to get closures in C?

It would be truly awesome!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using [FFCALL](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/libffcall/),

```
#include <callback.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static void incrementer_(int *in) {
    ++*in;
}
static void emitter_(int *in) {
    printf("%d\n", *in);
}
int main() {
    int in1 = 10, in2 = 20;
    int (*incrementer1)() = alloc_callback(&incrementer_, &in1);
    int (*emitter1)() = alloc_callback(&emitter_, &in1);
    int (*incrementer2)() = alloc_callback(&incrementer_, &in2);
    int (*emitter2)() = alloc_callback(&emitter_, &in2);
    incrementer1();
    incrementer2();
    emitter1();
    emitter2();
    free_callback(incrementer1);
    free_callback(incrementer2);
    free_callback(emitter1);
    free_callback(emitter2);
}
```

But usually in C you end up passing extra arguments around to fake closures.

---

Apple has a non-standard extension to C called [blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29), which do work much like closures.

Comment: Aren't blocks only a part of Objective-C? Can you compile pure C as C (and not simply ObjC without objects or messaging) and use blocks?

Comment: @outis: I believe that Apple added blocks support to GCC and clang in all C-related languages, not just Objective-C.  But I don't have an OS X machine to test it out on.

Comment: you're right. Just tested it, and it works in pure C. Didn't test C++, but that probably works, too.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer probably.  I'm still thinking about whether I am just a small dainty little trick away from getting it with that nice syntax without having to resort to lots of c style pointers and de-references.

Comment: This does not come close to compiling for me, despite fixing the obvious typos. This was the only example of closures using `ffcall` that I could find. I struggled with the man page for quite a while before giving up making it work. Nor are there any examples for `libffi` closures to be found either, which makes me think no one uses these libraries for closures.

Comment: @Liam libffi's closures are borderline insane.  The documentation is either incomplete or downright inaccurate, I forget which.  I eventually got them to work, but it took several weeks of fiddling, wild guesses, and some trial and error.  (With that said, what I was trying to use libffi's closures for wasn't true closures, either.)

Answer (score 20):

**A Working Definition of a Closure with a JavaScript Example**

A closure is a kind of object that contains a pointer or reference of some kind to a function to be executed along with the an instance of the data needed by the function.

An example in JavaScript from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures is

```
function makeAdder(x) {
  return function(y) { // create the adder function and return it along with
    return x + y;      // the captured data needed to generate its return value
  };
}
```

which could then be used like:

```
var add5 = makeAdder(5);  // create an adder function which adds 5 to its argument

console.log(add5(2));  // displays a value of 2 + 5 or 7
```

**Some of the Obstacles to Overcome with C**

The C programming language is a statically typed language, unlike JavaScript, nor does it have garbage collection, and some other features that make it easy to do closures in JavaScript or other languages with intrinsic support for closures.

One large obstacle for closures in Standard C is the lack of language support for the kind of construct in the JavaScript example in which the closure includes not only the function but also a copy of data that is captured when the closure is created, a way of saving state which can then be used when the closure is executed along with any additional arguments provided at the time the closure function is invoked.

However C does have some basic building blocks which can provide the tools for creating a kind of closure. Some of the difficulties are (1) memory management is the duty of the programmer, no garbage collection, (2) functions and data are separated, no classes or class type mechanics, (3) statically typed so no run time discovery of data types or data sizes, and (4) poor language facilities for capturing state data at the time the closure is created.

One thing that makes something of a closure facility possible with C is the `void *` pointer and using `unsigned char` as a kind of general purpose memory type which is then transformed into other types through casting.

**An update with new approach**

My original posted answer seems to have been helpful enough that people have upvoted it however it had a constraint or two that I didn't like.

Getting a notification of a recent upvote, I took a look at some of the other posted answers and realized that I could provide a second approach that would overcome the problem that bothered me.

**A new approach that removes a problem of the original approach**

The original approach required function arguments to be passed on the stack. This new approach eliminates that requirement. It also seems much cleaner. I'm keeping the original approach below.

The new approach uses a single `struct`, `ClosureStruct`, along with two functions to build the closure, `makeClosure()` and `pushClosureArg()`.

This new approach also uses the variable argument functionality of `stdarg.h` to process the captured arguments in the closure data.

Using the following in a C source code file requires the following includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


typedef struct {
    void (*p)();            // pointer to the function of this closure
    size_t  sargs;          // size of the memory area allocated for closure data
    size_t  cargs;          // current memory area in use for closure data
    unsigned char * args;   // pointer to the allocated closure data area
} ClosureStruct;

void * makeClosure(void (*p)(), size_t sargs)
{
    // allocate the space for the closure management data and the closure data itself.
    // we do this with a single call to calloc() so that we have only one pointer to
    // manage.
    ClosureStruct* cp = calloc(1, sizeof(ClosureStruct) + sargs);

    if (cp) {
        cp->p = p;             // save a pointer to the function
        cp->sargs = sargs;     // save the total size of the memory allocated for closure data
        cp->cargs = 0;         // initialize the amount of memory used
        cp->args = (unsigned char *)(cp + 1);  // closure data is after closure management block
    }

    return cp;
}

void * pushClosureArg(void* cp, size_t sarg, void* arg)
{
    if (cp) {
        ClosureStruct* p = cp;
        if (p->cargs + sarg <= p->sargs) {
            // there is room in the closure area for this argument so make a copy
            // of the argument and remember our new end of memory.
            memcpy(p->args + p->cargs, arg, sarg);
            p->cargs += sarg;
        }
    }

    return cp;
}
```

This code is then used similar to the following:

```
// example functions that we will use with closures

// funcadd() is a function that accepts a closure with two int arguments
// along with three additional int arguments.
// it is similar to the following function declaration:
//  void funcadd(int x1, int x2, int a, int b, int c);
//
void funcadd(ClosureStruct* cp, int a, int b, int c)
{
    // using the variable argument functionality we will set our
    // variable argument list address to the closure argument memory area
    // and then start pulling off the arguments that are provided by the closure.
    va_list jj;
    va_start(jj, cp->args);    // get the address of the first argument

    int x1 = va_arg(jj, int);    // get the first argument of the closure
    int x2 = va_arg(jj, int);

    printf("funcadd() = %d\n", a + b + c + x1 + x2);
}

int zFunc(ClosureStruct* cp, int j, int k)
{
    va_list jj;

    va_start(jj, cp->args);    // get the address of the first argument
    int i = va_arg(jj, int);

    printf("zFunc() i = %d, j = %d, k = %d\n", i, j, k);
    return i + j + k;
}

typedef struct { char xx[24]; } thing1;

int z2func( ClosureStruct* cp, int i)
{
    va_list jj;

    va_start(jj, cp->args);    // get the address of the first argument
    thing1 a = va_arg(jj, thing1);

    printf("z2func() i = %d, %s\n", i, a.xx);
    return 0;
}

int mainxx(void)
{
    ClosureStruct* p;

    int x;
    thing1 xpxp = { "1234567890123" };

    p = makeClosure(funcadd, 256);
    x = 4;  pushClosureArg(p, sizeof(int), &x);
    x = 10;  pushClosureArg(p, sizeof(int), &x);

    p->p(p, 1, 2, 3);

    free(p);

    p = makeClosure(z2func, sizeof(thing1));
    pushClosureArg(p, sizeof(thing1), &xpxp);

    p->p(p, 45);
    free(p);

    p = makeClosure(zFunc, sizeof(int));
    x = 5; pushClosureArg(p, sizeof(int), &x);

    p->p(p, 12, 7);

    return 0;
}
```

The output from the above usage is:

```
funcadd() = 20
z2func() i = 45, 1234567890123
zFunc() i = 5, j = 12, k = 7
```

However there is an issue with the above implementation, you have no way of getting the return value of a function that returns a value. In other words, the function `zFunc()` used in a closure above returns an `int` value which is ignored. If you try to capture the return value with something like `int k = pint->p(pint, 12, 7);` you will get an error message because the function pointer argument of `ClosureStruct` is `void (*p)();` rather than `int (*p)();`.

To work around this restraint, we will add two C Preprocessor macros to help us create individual versions of the `ClosureStruct` struct that specify a function return type other than `void`.

```
#define NAME_CLOSURE(t) ClosureStruct_ ## t

#define DEF_CLOSURE(t) \
typedef struct {      \
t (*p)();             \
size_t  sargs;        \
size_t  cargs;        \
unsigned char* args;  \
} NAME_CLOSURE(t);
```

We then redefine the two functions, `zFunc()` and `z2func()`, as follows using the macros.

```
DEF_CLOSURE(int)      // define closure struct that returns an int

int zFunc(NAME_CLOSURE(int)* cp, int j, int k)
{
    va_list jj;

    va_start(jj, cp->args);    // get the address of the first argument
    int i = va_arg(jj, int);

    printf("zFunc() i = %d, j = %d, k = %d\n", i, j, k);
    return i + j + k;
}

typedef struct { char xx[24]; } thing1;

int z2func( NAME_CLOSURE(int) * cp, int i)
{
    va_list jj;

    va_start(jj, cp->args);    // get the address of the first argument
    thing1 a = va_arg(jj, thing1);

    printf("z2func() i = %d, %s\n", i, a.xx);
    return 0;
}
```

And we use this as follows:

```
int mainxx(void)
{
    ClosureStruct* p;
    NAME_CLOSURE(int) *pint;

    int x;
    thing1 xpxp = { "1234567890123" };

    p = makeClosure(funcadd, 256);
    x = 4;  pushClosureArg(p, sizeof(int), &x);
    x = 10;  pushClosureArg(p, sizeof(int), &x);

    p->p(p, 1, 2, 3);

    free(p);

    pint = makeClosure(z2func, sizeof(thing1));
    pushClosureArg(pint, sizeof(thing1), &xpxp);

    int k = pint->p(pint, 45);

    free(pint);

    pint = makeClosure(zFunc, sizeof(int));
    x = 5; pushClosureArg(pint, sizeof(int), &x);

    k = pint->p(pint, 12, 7);
    return 0;
}
```

**First Implementation With Standard C and a Bit of Stretching Here and There**

**NOTE:** *The following example depends on a stack based argument passing convention as is used with most x86 32 bit compilers. Most compilers also allow for a calling convention to be specified other than stack based argument passing such as the `__fastcall` modifier of Visual Studio. The default for x64 and 64 bit Visual Studio is to use the `__fastcall` convention by default so that function arguments are passed in registers and not on the stack. See [Overview of x64 Calling Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) in the Microsoft MSDN as well as [How to set function arguments in assembly during runtime in a 64bit application on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283616/how-to-set-function-arguments-in-assembly-during-runtime-in-a-64bit-application) as well as the various answers and comments in [How are variable arguments implemented in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371450/how-are-variable-arguments-implemented-in-gcc) .*

One thing that we can do is to solve this problem of providing some kind of closure facility for C is to simplify the problem. Better to provide an 80% solution that is useful for a majority of applications than no solution at all.

One such simplification is to only support functions that do not return a value, in other words functions declared as `void func_name()`. We are also going to give up compile time type checking of the function argument list since this approach builds the function argument list at run time. Neither one of these things that we are giving up are trivial so the question is whether the value of this approach to closures in C outweighs what we are giving up.

First of all lets define our closure data area. The closure data area represents the memory area we are going to use to contain the information we need for a closure. The minimum amount of data I can think of is a pointer to the function to execute and a copy of the data to be provided to the function as arguments.

In this case we are going to provide any captured state data needed by the function as an argument to the function.

We also want to have some basic safe guards in place so that we will fail reasonably safely. Unfortunately the safety rails are a bit weak with some of the work arounds we are using to implement a form of closures.

**The Source Code**

The following source code was developed using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition in a .c C source file.

The data area is a struct that contains some management data, a pointer to the function, and an open ended data area.

```
typedef struct {
    size_t  nBytes;    // current number of bytes of data
    size_t  nSize;     // maximum size of the data area
    void(*pf)();       // pointer to the function to invoke
    unsigned char args[1];   // beginning of the data area for function arguments
} ClosureStruct;
```

Next we create a function that will initialize a closure data area.

```
ClosureStruct * beginClosure(void(*pf)(), int nSize, void *pArea)
{
    ClosureStruct *p = pArea;

    if (p) {
        p->nBytes = 0;      // number of bytes of the data area in use
        p->nSize = nSize - sizeof(ClosureStruct);   // max size of the data area
        p->pf = pf;         // pointer to the function to invoke
    }

    return p;
}
```

This function is designed to accept a pointer to a data area which gives flexibility as to how the user of the function wants to manage memory. They can either use some memory on the stack or static memory or they can use heap memory via the `malloc()` function.

```
unsigned char closure_area[512];
ClosureStruct *p = beginClosure (xFunc, 512, closure_area);
```

or

```
ClosureStruct *p = beginClosure (xFunc, 512, malloc(512));
//  do things with the closure
free (p);  // free the malloced memory.
```

Next we provide a function that allows us to add data and arguments to our closure. The purpose of this function is to build up the closure data so that when closure function is invoked, the closure function will be provided any data it needs to do its job.

```
ClosureStruct * pushDataClosure(ClosureStruct *p, size_t size, ...)
{
    if (p && p->nBytes + size < p->nSize) {
        va_list jj;

        va_start(jj, size);    // get the address of the first argument

        memcpy(p->args + p->nBytes, jj, size);  // copy the specified size to the closure memory area.
        p->nBytes += size;     // keep up with how many total bytes we have copied
        va_end(jj);
    }

    return p;
}
```

And to make this a bit simpler to use lets provide a wrapping macro which is generally handy but does have limitations since it is C Processor text manipulation.

```
#define PUSHDATA(cs,d) pushDataClosure((cs),sizeof(d),(d))
```

so we could then use something like the following source code:

```
unsigned char closurearea[256];
int  iValue = 34;

ClosureStruct *dd = PUSHDATA(beginClosure(z2func, 256, closurearea), iValue);
dd = PUSHDATA(dd, 68);
execClosure(dd);
```

**Invoking the Closure: The execClosure() Function**

The last piece to this is the `execClosure()` function to execute the closure function with its data. What we are doing in this function is to copy the argument list supplied in the closure data structure onto the stack as we invoke the function.

What we do is cast the args area of the closure data to a pointer to a struct containing an `unsigned char` array and then dereference the pointer so that the C compiler will put a copy of the arguments onto the stack before it calls the function in the closure.

To make it easier to create the `execClosure()` function, we will create a macro that makes it easy to create the various sizes of structs we need.

```
// helper macro to reduce type and reduce chance of typing errors.

#define CLOSEURESIZE(p,n)  if ((p)->nBytes < (n)) { \
struct {\
unsigned char x[n];\
} *px = (void *)p->args;\
p->pf(*px);\
}
```

Then we use this macro to create a series of tests to determine how to call the closure function. The sizes chosen here may need tweaking for particular applications. These sizes are arbitrary and since the closure data will rarely be of the same size, this is not efficiently using stack space. And there is the possibility that there may be more closure data than we have allowed for.

```
// execute a closure by calling the function through the function pointer
// provided along with the created list of arguments.
ClosureStruct * execClosure(ClosureStruct *p)
{
    if (p) {
        // the following structs are used to allocate a specified size of
        // memory on the stack which is then filled with a copy of the
        // function argument list provided in the closure data.
        CLOSEURESIZE(p,64)
        else CLOSEURESIZE(p, 128)
        else CLOSEURESIZE(p, 256)
        else CLOSEURESIZE(p, 512)
        else CLOSEURESIZE(p, 1024)
        else CLOSEURESIZE(p, 1536)
        else CLOSEURESIZE(p, 2048)
    }

    return p;
}
```

We return the pointer to the closure in order to make it easily available.

**An Example Using the Library Developed**

We can use the above as follows. First a couple of example functions that don't really do much.

```
int zFunc(int i, int j, int k)
{
    printf("zFunc i = %d, j = %d, k = %d\n", i, j, k);
    return i + j + k;
}

typedef struct { char xx[24]; } thing1;

int z2func(thing1 a, int i)
{
    printf("i = %d, %s\n", i, a.xx);
    return 0;
}
```

Next we build our closures and execute them.

```
{
    unsigned char closurearea[256];
    thing1 xpxp = { "1234567890123" };
    thing1 *ypyp = &xpxp;
    int  iValue = 45;

    ClosureStruct *dd = PUSHDATA(beginClosure(z2func, 256, malloc(256)), xpxp);
    free(execClosure(PUSHDATA(dd, iValue)));

    dd = PUSHDATA(beginClosure(z2func, 256, closurearea), *ypyp);
    dd = PUSHDATA(dd, 68);
    execClosure(dd);

    dd = PUSHDATA(beginClosure(zFunc, 256, closurearea), iValue);
    dd = PUSHDATA(dd, 145);
    dd = PUSHDATA(dd, 185);
    execClosure(dd);
}
```

Which gives an output of

```
i = 45, 1234567890123
i = 68, 1234567890123
zFunc i = 45, j = 145, k = 185
```

**Well What About Currying?**

Next we could make a modification to our closure struct to allow us to do currying of functions.

```
typedef struct {
    size_t  nBytes;    // current number of bytes of data
    size_t  nSize;     // maximum size of the data area
    size_t  nCurry;    // last saved nBytes for curry and additional arguments
    void(*pf)();       // pointer to the function to invoke
    unsigned char args[1];   // beginning of the data area for function arguments
} ClosureStruct;
```

with the supporting functions for currying and resetting of a curry point being

```
ClosureStruct *curryClosure(ClosureStruct *p)
{
    p->nCurry = p->nBytes;
    return p;
}
ClosureStruct *resetCurryClosure(ClosureStruct *p)
{
    p->nBytes = p->nCurry;
    return p;
}
```

The source code for testing this could be:

```
{
    unsigned char closurearea[256];
    thing1 xpxp = { "1234567890123" };
    thing1 *ypyp = &xpxp;
    int  iValue = 45;

    ClosureStruct *dd = PUSHDATA(beginClosure(z2func, 256, malloc(256)), xpxp);
    free(execClosure(PUSHDATA(dd, iValue)));
    dd = PUSHDATA(beginClosure(z2func, 256, closurearea), *ypyp);
    dd = PUSHDATA(dd, 68);
    execClosure(dd);
    dd = PUSHDATA(beginClosure(zFunc, 256, closurearea), iValue);
    dd = PUSHDATA(dd, 145);
    dd = curryClosure(dd);
    dd = resetCurryClosure(execClosure(PUSHDATA(dd, 185)));
    dd = resetCurryClosure(execClosure(PUSHDATA(dd, 295)));
}
```

with the output of

```
i = 45, 1234567890123
i = 68, 1234567890123
zFunc i = 45, j = 145, k = 185
zFunc i = 45, j = 145, k = 295
```

Answer (score 17):

The ANSI C has not a support for closure, as well as nested functions. Workaround for it is usage simple "struct".

Simple example closure for sum two numbers.

```
// Structure for keep pointer for function and first parameter
typedef struct _closure{
    int x;
    char* (*call)(struct _closure *str, int y);
} closure;


// An function return a result call a closure as string
char *
sumY(closure *_closure, int y) {
    char *msg = calloc(20, sizeof(char));
    int sum = _closure->x + y;
    sprintf(msg, "%d + %d = %d", _closure->x, y, sum);
    return msg;
}


// An function return a closure for sum two numbers
closure *
sumX(int x) {
    closure *func = (closure*)malloc(sizeof(closure));
    func->x = x;
    func->call = sumY;
    return func;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main (int argv, char **argc)
{

    closure *sumBy10 = sumX(10);
    puts(sumBy10->call(sumBy10, 1));
    puts(sumBy10->call(sumBy10, 3));
    puts(sumBy10->call(sumBy10, 2));
    puts(sumBy10->call(sumBy10, 4));
    puts(sumBy10->call(sumBy10, 5));
}
```

Result:

```
10 + 1 = 11
10 + 3 = 13
10 + 2 = 12
10 + 4 = 14
10 + 5 = 15
```

On C++11 it will be achived by use lambda expression.

```
#include <iostream>
int main (int argv, char **argc)
{
    int x = 10;
    auto sumBy10 = [x] (int y) {
        std::cout << x << " + " << y << " = " << x + y << std::endl;
    };
    sumBy10(1);
    sumBy10(2);
    sumBy10(3);
    sumBy10(4);
    sumBy10(5);
}
```

A result, after compilation with a flag -std=c++11.

```
10 + 1 = 11
10 + 2 = 12
10 + 3 = 13
10 + 4 = 14
10 + 5 = 15
```

Comment: you allocated memory but never freed them

Comment: @phuclv, it's okay because the OS will free it after the `sumBy10(5);` line completes.  Never do extra work that your OS will do for you for free.

Comment: @jdk1.0 that may be fine for code in `main` in this case, but that's a bad idea as you'll get used to it without notice and forget to free other allocated memory. It also prevents you from using a leak detector. And what if the code is moved to a function and called before something needs lots of memory and you don't know you have to add `free` ? I've seen production bugs due to that reason. [Should I free memory before exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36584062/995714)

Comment: @phuclv But as the [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584062/should-i-free-memory-before-exit/36584509#36584509) there says, it is *not* a given that freeing everything before exit is necessary, or that failing to free something is Wrong.

Answer (score 8):

GCC and clang have the blocks extension, which is essentially closures in C.

Comment: Blocks are not in GCC mainline, only Apple's fork.

Comment: Apple has implemented blocks in Apple's own copy of the GCC sources and in the Clang LLVM compiler front end.

Answer (score 5):

The idiomatic way of doing it in is C is passing *a function pointer and a void pointer to the context*.

However, some time ago I came up with a different approach. Surprisingly, there is a family of builtin types in C that carries both a data and the code itself. Those are **pointers to a function pointer**.

The trick is use this single object to pass both the code by dereferencing a function pointer. And next passing the very same double function pointer as the context as a first argument. It looks a bit convoluted by actually it results in very flexible and readable machanism for closures.

See the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// typedefing functions makes usually makes code more readable
typedef double double_fun_t(void*, double);

struct exponential {
   // closure must be placed as the first member to allow safe casting
   // between a pointer to `closure` and `struct exponential`
  double_fun_t *closure;
  double temperature;
};

double exponential(void *ctx_, double x) {
  struct exponential *ctx = ctx_;
  return exp(x / ctx->temperature);
}

// the "constructor" of the closure for exponential
double_fun_t **make_exponential(double temperature) {
  struct exponential *e = malloc(sizeof *e);
  e->closure = exponential;
  e->temperature = temperature;
  return &e->closure;
}

// now simple closure with no context, a pure x -> x*x mapping
double square(void *_unused, double x){
    (void)_unused;
    return x*x;
}

// use compound literal to transform a function to a closure
double_fun_t **square_closure = & (double_fun_t*) { square };

// the worker that process closures, note that `double_fun_t` is not used
// because `double(**)(void*,double)` is builtin type
double somme(double* liste, int length, double (**fun)(void*,double)){
    double poids = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<length;++i)
        // calling a closure, note that `fun` is used for both obtaing
        // the function pointer and for passing the context
        poids = poids + (*fun)(fun, liste[i]);
    return poids;
}

int main(void) {
    double list[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    
    printf("%g\n", somme(list, 3, square_closure));

    // a dynamic closure
    double_fun_t **exponential = make_exponential(42);
    printf("%g\n", somme(list, 3, exponential));
    free(exponential);

    return 0;
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that the closure exports a pure interface for calling double->double functions. There is no need to introduce any boxing structures used by *all* clients of the closure. The only requirement is the "calling convention" which is very natural and does not require sharing any code.

Answer (score 2):

GCC supports inner functions, but not closures. C++0x will have closures. No version of C that I'm aware of, and certainly no standard version, provides that level of awesome.

[Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/index.html), which is part of Boost, provides closures in C++.

Comment: Can you think of a crafty way to massage C into achieving what we are looking for here without polluting the syntax or requiring extra libraries?  It sounds so close.

Comment: No. Since there's no language level support, you'll need library support. Since the closest you can get to extending the language itself is to use macros and there's no overloading, you'll need special syntax, possibly hidden behind macros.

Comment: Well I know that it's not an intended feature of C --- but doing object oriented inheritance through a bunch of struct and macro magic was also not a planned use.  The problem is the reuse of address space and the temporality of the pointers...The key reason is simple, "C is not that kind of language". And even if you get the private function and variable part down; which is what OO offers, you still lack anonymous functions - a major component to making it useful; and that would undoubtedly require macros.

Comment: C can support other styles of programming, but you still have to rely on C's capabilities and procedural syntax. Even the example of OO style in C still relies on pointers and procedures. Closures are still beyond the capabilities of C; if you look at FFCALL's source, it uses assembly language to build closures. FFCALL is about as clean as you can get.

Answer (score 2):

On this page you can find a description on how to do closures in C:

http://brodowsky.it-sky.net/2014/06/20/closures-in-c-and-scala/

The idea is that a struct is needed and that struct contains the function pointer, but gets provided to the function as first argument. Apart from the fact that it requires a lot of boiler plate code and the memory management is off course an issue, this works and provides the power and possibilities of other languages' closures.

Comment: That's conceptually very simple, once you get past the boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `-fblocks` flag, but it does not look so nice like in JS or TS:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Block.h>

#define NEW(T) ({ \
    T* __ret = (T*)calloc(1, sizeof(T)); \
    __ret; \
})

typedef struct data_t {
    int value;
} data_t;

typedef struct object_t {
    int (^get)(void);
    void (^set)(int);
    void (^free)(void);
} object_t;

object_t const* object_create(void) {
    data_t* priv = NEW(data_t);
    object_t* pub = NEW(object_t);

    priv->value = 123;

    pub->get = Block_copy(^{
        return priv->value;
    });

    pub->set = Block_copy(^(int value){
        priv->value = value;
    });

    pub->free = Block_copy(^{
        free(priv);
        free(pub);
    });

    return pub;
}

int main() {
    object_t const* obj = object_create();
    printf("before: %d\n", obj->get());
    obj->set(321);
    printf("after: %d\n", obj->get());
    obj->free();
    return 0;
}
```

```sh
clang main.c -o main.o -fblocks -fsanitize=address; ./main.o
```

```
before: 123
after: 321
```

Comment: Is there any reason why not do `#define NEW(T) ((T*)calloc(1, sizeof(T)))` ? Why rely on compiler specific extensions?
`

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
File Conventions
----------------
alignment: similar statements only
           int    a = 10;
           int* omg = {120, 5};
functions: dofunction(a, b, c);
macros:    _do_macro(a, b, c);
variables: int dovariable=10;
*/


////Macros

#define _assert(got, expected, teardownmacro) \
  do { \
    if((got)!=(expected)) { \
      fprintf(stderr, "line %i: ", __LINE__); \
      fprintf(stderr, "%i != %i\n", (got), (expected)); \
      teardownmacro; \
      return EXIT_FAILURE; \
    } \
  } while(0);


////Internal Helpers

static void istarted() {
  fprintf(stderr, "Start tests\n");
}

static void iended() {
  fprintf(stderr, "End tests\n");
}

////Tests

int main(void)
{
  ///Environment

  int  localvar = 0;
  int* localptr = NULL;


  ///Closures

#define _setup_test(mvar, msize) \
  do { \
    localptr=calloc((msize), sizeof(int)); \
    localvar=(mvar); \
  } while(0);

#define _teardown_test() \
  do { \
    free(localptr); \
    localptr=NULL; \
  } while(0);

  
  ///Tests
  
  istarted();

  _setup_test(10, 2);
  _assert(localvar, 10, _teardown_test());
  _teardown_test();

  _setup_test(100, 5);
  _assert(localvar, 100, _teardown_test());
  _teardown_test();

  iended();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Context**

I was curious about how others accomplished this in C. I wasn't totally surprised when I didn't see this answer. **Warning: This answer is not for beginners.**

I live a lot more in the Unix style of thinking: lots of my personal programs and libraries are small and do one thing very well. **Macros as "closures"** are much safer in this context. I believe all the **organization and specified conventions for readability is super important**, so the code is readable by us later, and a macro looks like a macro and a function looks like a function. To clarify, not literally these personal conventions, just having some, that are specified and followed to distinguish different language constructs (macros and functions). We all should be doing that anyway.

Don't do afraid of macros. **When it makes sense: use them. The advanced part is the when.** My example is one example of the whens. They are ridiculously powerful and not that scary.

**Rambling**

I sometimes use a proper closure/lambda in other languages to execute a set of expressions over and over within a function. It's a little context aware private helper function. Regardless of its proper definition, that's something a closure can do. It helps me write less code. Another benefit of this is you don't need to reference a struct to know how to use it or understand what it's doing. The other answers do not have this benefit, and, if it wasn't obvious I hold readability very highly. I strive for simple legible solutions. This one time I wrote an iOS app and it was wonderful and as simple as I could get it. Then I wrote the same "app" in bash in like 5 lines of code and cursed.

Also embedded systems.

Comment: I totally feel your "Also embedded systems" comment deep down in my gut. In my other browser tab I'm providing feedback on a code review from a developer that totally does not get layered library design for usage in an embedded system. I've got more total comments against one header file than there are lines in the header file.

Comment: The code does not implement anything I can recognise as a closure.

Comment: @LHP What properties of some code mean closure to you?

Comment: I could take a definition from WP for example: "a closure is a record storing a function together with an environment". The code as I see it above contains nothing I can interpret as such. There are no function pointers, the macros are simply allocating locallptr to some size and assigning localvar some integer, then freeing and NULLing localptr after asserting that the value stored in localvar is the value that was indeed stored in localvar. At no point is a function called that captures this "environment" (as the comment suggest it to be), nor...

Comment: ...nor is a record containing a pointer to such a function and pointers to the "environment" variables constructed and passed to some other function as an argument. No closures in sight - but it could just be my eyes failing. Maybe your intention was something else, but then clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value in the closure itself, and you can't call the functions without arguments unless you use a library like [libffcall](https://www.gnu.org/software/libffcall/).

This is the most straightforward way to implement what you want in standard C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct closure {
    int n;
    void (*incrementer) (struct closure *);
    void (*emitter) (struct closure *);
};

void main(void)
{
    void incrementer(struct closure *c) {
        c->n++;
    }
    void emitter(struct closure *c) {
        printf("%d\n", c->n);
    }

    struct closure test[] = {
        { n: 10, incrementer: incrementer, emitter: emitter },
        { n: 20, incrementer: incrementer, emitter: emitter },
    };

    test[0].incrementer(&test[0]);
    test[1].incrementer(&test[1]);

    test[0].emitter(&test[0]);
    test[1].emitter(&test[1]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've seen many good examples, but maybe this one will also help, since function recursion is similar to lisp... Since function calls are less efficient than loops, perhaps register calls should be used. Since this seems similar to your solutions, I put this idea to think about as well.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int first(int a) {
    if(a > 0) {
        a--;
        printf("%d\n", a);
        first(a);
    }
}

int main() {
    first(20);
}

/*int first2(int a, void (*b)[]()) {
    if(a > 0) {
        a--;
        b[a](c);
        first(a, &b());
    }
}

int first1(int c, void (*b)()) {
    if(c > 0) {
        b(c);
        a--;
        first(c, &b);
    }
}

int main() {
    first1(680, first2(5, (*fun)[]()));
}*/
```

This example could draw 5 function shapes on a 680px wide screen... I hope this also helps in finding the best solution for your needs!