# reducing the number of arguments in functions in C

Tags: c, parameter-passing, numerical-integration

I want to do a numerical integration of a function f using the qtrap function defined in "Numerical recipes in C".

```
double qtrap(double (*func)(double), double a, double b);
```

As shown, it is a 1-d integration of a variable of type double.

But the function I want to integrate has an additional parameter a:

```
double f(double x, int a)
{
    return a + x * x;
}
```

Now I am looking for a way to integrate f for different values of a.

My idea up to now:

```
typedef double (*fctp1_t)(double);       //function pointer type for 1 arg
typedef double (*fctp2_t)(double, int);  //function pointer type for 2 args

int a = 10;
fctp1_t = f1d;
f1d = reduceArgument(f, a);

qtrap(f1d, 0, 1);
```

with the reduceArgument something like this:

```
fctp1_t reduceArgument(fctp2_t f2d, int ia)
{
    return f2d(x, ia);
}
```

This code results in the error: 'x' undeclared.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and **mind the warnings**.

Comment: Well, with -Wall I get no compiler warnings.

Comment: You have a random variable `x` in your code. Obviously compiler doesn't know what to do with it, but neither do we.

Comment: x is the integration variable of the function f. I see that the compiler cannot handle the x; this is why I got stuck; this is why I am asking the question. I hope the problem is clear for a human mind.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393716/is-there-a-a-way-to-achieve-closures-in-c

Comment: Well ... in `fctp1_t = f1d;` you're trying to assign *something* (I assumed this *something* is defined) to a type. I didn't test any compiler, but assumed any half decent one would complain.

Comment: Can you *fork* `qtrap()` to something like `double qtrap2(double (*func)(double, int), double a, double b);`?

Answer (score 0):

C does not allow to build a function like that.  You have two way to solve your problem:

- modify qtrap so that it is able to handle a parametrized function;
- use a global variable to pass the parameter implicitly.