# Pass member function as argument

Tags: c++, oop

I have a function that runs a callback:

```
void run_callback(void(*callback)(uint32_t)) {
    callback(100);
}
```

This works with static functions,

```
void global_callback(uint32_t);

int main() {
    run_callback(global_callback);
}
```

but not with member functions.

```
class A {
    int x;
  public:
    void callback(uint32_t);
};

int main() {
    A foo;
    run_callback(foo.callback);
}
```

I work around this with a static wrapper function.

```
void run_member_callback(void* obj, void(*callback)(void*,uint32_t)) {
    callback(obj, 100);
}

class B {
    int x;
  public:
    static void static_callback(void* obj, uint32_t value) {
        static_cast<B*>(obj)->callback(value);
    }
    void callback(uint32_t);
};

int main() {
    B foo;
    run_member_callback(&foo, foo.static_callback);
}
```

Is there a simple way to pass a member function as an argument?

*edit:*
I'm trying to avoid STL, and templates aren't an option since my implementation of `run_callback` is virtual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a method and a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)

Comment: That's real close, @Tim , but not quite close enough. Here's another almost-duplicate:[How can I pass a member function where a free function is expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/how-can-i-pass-a-member-function-where-a-free-function-is-expected) Put them to gether and you get some [Bibbidi Bobbidi Boo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNKuARjkWEg).

Comment: Some good general purpose reading on the topic: [Pointers to Member Functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Comment: That kind of code could be fragile particularly if you have multiple inheritance. Better to remplace your `void *` with `B *` and reduce the number of cast. And also use pointer to member functions.

Comment: Is `run_callback` a function that you wrote and can change, or is it from some library or API that you have to use as-is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a a way to achieve closures in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393716/is-there-a-a-way-to-achieve-closures-in-c)

Comment: You are trying to create a closure in C, for this to work you will need to generate some code at runtime - this is what FFCALL-library will do for you, your workaround is basically the standard way for to achieve the same goal, if the signature of the callback can be changed.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing some weird, C-ish things. Use C++ features. I personally would use a template for `run_callback` and a lambda for passing the member function:

```
template <class F>
void run_callback(F callback)
{
    callback(100);
}

class A
{
    int x;
  public:
    void callback(uint32_t);
};

int main()
{
    A foo{};
    run_callback([&](uint32_t a) { return foo.callback(a); });
}
```

If you capture the object by reference take care it outlives the `run_callback` call. Otherwise capture it by value.

---

[What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: In some case, it might be useful to use `std::function<void(uint32_t)>` instead for example if `run_callback` is complex and used with different argument types.

Comment: @Phil1970 avoid `std::function` unless you really need the type erasure (like storing functions in a collection). It adds considerable overhead and has a notably performance hit.

Comment: @bolov That was my concern.