# Function that returns a pointer to function using parameter passed

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

I'm a bit confused as to how to implement the following. I want to have a function, `func2`, return a function that with call `func1` with the specified parameters:

```
int func1(int x, int y, int z, int type){
    
    // Calculations
}

int ((*func2)(int x, int y, int z))(int type){

    // Return a pointer to func1 that with get x, y, z as parameters 
    // when called later, with type = type being fixed
}
```

Use:

```
my_func = func2(3);
printf("result = %d\n", my_func(1,2,3));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a a way to achieve closures in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393716/is-there-a-a-way-to-achieve-closures-in-c)

Comment: There are lots of existing answers to this question.  See the duplicate link.  Some use FFCALL, and some are just straight C.

Comment: Hm, it looks like GNU has a [callback library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libffcall/callback.html) as well.  The advantage to these solutions is that they give you a callable function that has its own associated state.  Unfortunately, there's no way to implement this directly in C.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you need something called a *closure* which is basically a record with the function and the type as fields. Below is an example to illustrate the idea. In a real program you also need to check that malloc doesn't return NULL, and free the memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ClosureDesc *Closure;

struct ClosureDesc {
    int type;
    int (*function)(Closure c, int x, int y, int z);
};


int func1(Closure c, int x, int y, int z)
{
    return c->type;
}


Closure func2(int type)
{
    Closure c;

    c = malloc(sizeof *c);
    c->type = type;
    c->function = func1;
    return c;
}


int main(void)
{
    Closure my_func;

    my_func = func2(3);
    printf("result = %d\n", my_func->function(my_func, 1,2,3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You left out the all-important step of *freeing* the closure when done with it.  It would probably also be better not to bury the pointer in a `typedef`, but instead expose it so people are aware of it (which probably would have prevented the memory leak bug).

Comment: @TomKarzes Indeed but in this short example it will be freed when the program exits. Updated the answer to highlight this.

Comment: That's a bad way to look at it.  OP will need to know how to use this in more than just a "wait until exit to free everything" context.  And it has the bad practice of hiding the pointer in a `typedef`, which makes it that much more likely that it will have bugs like this.

Comment: but it does not select the correct function depending on the type. So where is the solution?

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland It all depends on how you interpret the question.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom he wants function returning a pointer to function depending on the parameter. IMO it is quite clear

Comment: Thank you for trying to provide me with a solution! Though, I'd prefer it if there was a way to call a function immediately wihtout accessing the member of a structure. type, participates in the calculations performed and can take a wide range of numbers - so it can't be used as a function selector.

Comment: @Ccret Unfortunately, C unlike e.g. Javascript does not support this.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Thank you, unfortunately there seems to be no workaround.

Comment: @Ccret If you explain the underlying problem (in a different question) there may be another solution. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers syntax is a bit confusing but you can make it easier typedefing the functions itself. Then you can use "normal" pointer syntax.

```
typedef int func(int,int,int);

int func1(int x, int y, int z){
    // Calculations
    return 1;
}

int func2(int x, int y, int z){
    // Calculations
    return 2;
}

int func3(int x, int y, int z){
    // Calculations
    return 3;
}


func *selectfunc(int type)
{
    func *f = NULL;
    switch(type)
    {
        case 1:
            f = func1;
            break;
        case 2:
            f = func2;
            break;
        case 3:
            f = func3;
            break;
    }
    return f;
}


int main(void)
{
    int type = rand()%3;
    printf("%d", selectfunc(type)(1,2,3));
}
```

or

```
    func *fptr = selectfunc(2);
    fptr(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to provide me with a solution, close to the format I had in mind! Though, `type` can get a wide range of values and can't be used as a function selector.

Comment: it is only an example

Comment: It doesn't pass `type` to func1. I'd like `type` to get a value once and then this value to be used to perform calculations when calling `fptr(1,2,3)`.

Comment: so modify your question. Do you think that I read telepatically from your mind. In your example function pointer passes also **3** parameters

Comment: I think it's clear in the declaration of `func1` that it needs 4 parameters.

Comment: `func1(int x, int y, int z, int type)`

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I think you’re going for:

```
int func1( int x, int y, int z )
{
  ...
}

/**
 * func2 takes an integer parameter and returns a
 * pointer to a function that takes 3 integer
 * parameters and returns int
 */
int (*func2(int type))(int, int, int)
{
  /**
   * This example is based on what you wrote in your 
   * question.  Regardless of how you actually select
   * which function to return based on the input, the
   * return statement will be the same.
   */
  switch ( type )
  {
    case 3:
      return func1;
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main( void )
{
  int (*my_func)(int, int, int);
  ...
  my_func = func2( 3 );
  if ( my_func )
    printf( "result = %d\n", my_func( 1, 2, 3 ) );
  ...
}
```

If you write `func2` such that it can never return `NULL` *and* you want your co-workers to throw things at you, you can dispense with the `my_func` variable and just write

```
printf( "result = %d\n", func2(3)(1, 2, 3));
```

I wouldn’t recommend it though, unless you like rude comments in code reviews.