# Forward Declaration of Function Type in C

Tags: c, function, go, recursion, types

I want to declare a recursive function type (a function which declares itself) in C.

In a language like Go I can do:

```golang
type F func() F

func foo() F {
  return foo
}
```

If I try to do the equivalent in C:

```
typedef (*F)(F());
```

I get the following error from GCC:

```
main.c:1:14: error: unknown type name ‘F’
    1 | typedef (*F)(F());
```

Which makes sense because F doesn't exist at the time of its use. A forward declaration could fix this, how do you forward declare a function type in C?

Comment: I suspect the best you can do is to declare a function whose parameter is a function (automatically adjusted to be a pointer to a function) whose parameter is a function…, nested any number of levels deep to end in a function whose parameters are not specified (uses `()` for the argument list), such as `typedef int F(int (int (int (int ()))));`. In C, the scope of an identifier begins at the end of its declarator, and function declarators include the `(…)` specifying the parameters. And you cannot redeclare `typedef` identifiers with a different type, so you cannot complete it later.

Comment: Re "*`typedef (*F)(F());`*", I think you mean `typedef F *F( void );` (function type) or `typedef FPTR (*FPTR)( void );` (function pointer type). But this doesn't change the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C doesn't support recursive type definitions.

Exception: You can use a pointer to a struct type you haven't declared, so a struct type can include a pointer to a struct of the struct type being declared.

Also, you can apparently use a struct type you haven't yet declared as the return value of a function. So this is close to what you want:

```c
// This effectively gives us
// typedef struct { F *f } F( void );

typedef struct S S;

typedef S F( void );

struct S {
   F *f;
};

S foo() {
   return (S){ foo };
}

int main( void ) {
   F *f = foo;
   printf( "%p\n", (void*)f );

   f = f().f;
   printf( "%p\n", (void*)f );
}
```

Comment: But if you then want ways to create more values of type `F` by compounding other operations, that will be difficult or limited.

Comment: @aschepler, Ways to create more functions of type `F`? I don't follow.

Comment: As for difficult or limited? It's just a question of wrapping return values (or parameters) using `(S){ x }`, and unwrapping returned values (or arguments) using `x.f`. Not pretty, but hardly difficult. If you want pretty, just use a `void*` and live with the lack of type checking.

Comment: For example, can you write `F * curry(F*);` such that for any `f`, `curry(f)()` is functionally the same as `f`? Or `F * seq(F*, F*);` such that `seq(f,g)()` has the same side effects as `(f(), g())`?

Comment: @aschepler, Ah, you were commenting to the OP, not on my answer. C doesn't have closures, but there are libraries that introduce them. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4393716/589924).