# How to pass function pointer as arguments?

Tags: c, pointers

I have two function definitions

```
void USART_puts(USART_TypeDef* USARTx, volatile char *s)
{
 .....
}


void send_packet(char op, unsigned char *data, unsigned char len) 
{
....
}
```

now I have created a function pointer for send_packet(char,unsigned char*,unsigned char) as

```
void (*send_packet)(char,unsigned char*,unsigned char);
```

I want to pass this function pointer like this

```
 USART_Puts(USART1,send_packet)
```

But I am getting an error " argument of type send_packet * is incompatible with type volatile char * "
I can understand from the error that two arguments are not matching. But can anyone please tell me how can I pass this function pointer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789807/function-pointer-as-an-argument

Answer (score 1):

`USART_Puts` needs to have a parameter of function pointer type.

```
void USART_puts(USART_TypeDef* USARTx, void (*s)(char,unsigned char*,unsigned char))
```

The definition of `send_packet` as a pointer after its definition as a function is unnecessary. Two such declarations of the same name should not even coexist.

Comment: Apparently `USART_Puts` is part of a vendor API, so if he makes this change to the vendor-supplied header files then he is in for a world of hurt

Comment: @MattMcNabb Well, it'll have approximately the same effect as passing the function pointer as a data buffer by casting it. So, the question is actually, "how do I get asynchronous I/O from a driver without support?"