# Passing functions as parameters to button handlers in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, pebble-watch

I am working on a [smartwatch](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/) app written in C and I am trying to pass a function pointer as a parameter into my button handlers so it can be called from in there. So far I ve done the following but i get an error saying that the object I am calling is not a function.

```
void func(){
    ...
}

static void select_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context){
    context();
}

static void click_config_provider(void *context) {
    window_single_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_SELECT, select_click_handler);
    window_set_click_context(BUTTON_ID_SELECT, context);
}

int main(void){
    ...
    action_bar = action_bar_layer_create();
    action_bar_layer_set_click_config_provider(action_bar, click_config_provider);
    action_bar_layer_set_context(action_bar, &func);
}
```

Documentation:

[action_bar_layer_create](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/group___action_bar_layer.html#ga578ddbc9b97389839cf348e40a43abb9)

[action_bar_layer_set_click_config_provider](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/group___action_bar_layer.html#ga0abe5d50cc4845dc219bf69ca24b4466)

[action_bar_layer_set_context](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/group___action_bar_layer.html#ga4f5d63fd993859e5a6602e509aa20103)

Comment: on which line does the error occur?

Comment: error: called object 'context' is not a function. When trying to call it in the `select_click_handler`

Comment: `context` is not a function it's a `void *`. Are you sure the context is a function? If so, this will call for a cast, but I suspect the context is context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `select_click_handler()` function `context` is `void *` so you need to typecast it appropriately before calling it.

Assuming `context` is `func` you can do this

```
static void select_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context){
    ((void (*)(void)) context)();
}
```

Also in this line `action_bar_layer_set_context(action_bar, &func);` you don't need `&` just pass `func` not `&func`.

Comment: @Rakim, depends upon what is the function type you want to call.

Comment: @Rakim the function pointer generic prototype is `(return type)(*function name)(argumnet list)`

Answer (score 1):

In C, `void*` is used in many places to stand in for a generic pointer which can either be a pointer to a variable or a pointer to a function. You are making use of the latter.

At the point of use you need to *cast* it to the correct type else the runtime will not know what to do. In your case, the correct type is a function that takes no arguments and returns a `void`.

To do that, use `((void (*)(void *))context)()` at the calling site; within `select_click_handler`

Answer (score 0):

```
static void select_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context){
context();
}
```

In this, `context` is only pointer variable, not a function. so, You have to typecast or define it properly to use it for function calling.

But you are passing function pointer as argument. so, i hope these links help you

[Function pointer as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789807/function-pointer-as-an-argument)