# How to use a function argument of a function in the function implementation?

Tags: c, function-pointers

If I have a declaration like this:

```
int foo1 (int foo2 (int a));
```

How can I implement this `foo1` function? Like,

```
int foo1 (int foo2 (int a))
{
    // How can I use foo2 here, which is the argument?
}
```

And how do I call the `foo1` function in `main`? Like:

```
foo1(/* ??? */);
```

Comment: You mean you want to pass a function pointer as an argument to a function? See [Function pointer as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789807/function-pointer-as-an-argument)

Comment: What kind of syntax is this even? It seems to compile, but it's not a function pointer.

Comment: @lurker  but in my declaration, there is no a pointer. I have already see that topic.

Comment: @mkrieger1 It's a function pointer.

Comment: This compiles??

Comment: @machine_1 yes, it compiles

Comment: @melpomene , I can't see a pointer `*`, how could you say that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you declare a function parameter as a function, the compiler automatically adjusts its type to "pointer to function".

```
int foo1 (int foo2 (int a))
```

is exactly the same as

```
int foo1 (int (*foo2)(int a))
```

(This is similar to how declaring a function parameter as an array (e.g. `int foo2[123]`) automatically makes it a pointer instead (e.g. `int *foo2`).)

As for how you can use `foo2`: You can call it (e.g. `foo2(42)`) or you can dereference it (`*foo2`), which (as usual with functions) immediately decays back to a pointer again (which you can then call (e.g. `(*foo2)(42)`) or dereference again (`**foo2)`, which immediately decays back to a pointer, which ...).

To call `foo1`, you need to pass it a function pointer. If you don't have an existing function pointer around, you can define a new function (outside of `main`), such as:

```
int bar(int x) {
    printf("hello from bar, called with %d\n", x);
    return 2 * x;
}
```

Then you can do

```
foo1(&bar);  // pass a pointer to bar to foo1
```

or equivalently

```
foo1(bar);  // functions automatically decay to pointers anyway
```

Comment: If you have a Parameter `int foo2[123]` it's not exactly the same as a pointer. There is a difference with `sizeof`.

Comment: @harper No, there is no difference. Try it.

Comment: (This is similar to how declaring a function parameter as an array (e.g. int foo2[123]) automatically makes it a pointer instead (e.g. int *foo2).)

I don't think this is a technically correct statement. Though it may appear .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this simple example could help you :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo1 (int foo2 (int),int i);
int sub_one (int);
int add_one (int);

int main() {
    int i=10,j;
    j=foo1(sub_one,i);
    printf("%d\n",j);
    j=foo1(add_one,i);
    printf("%d\n",j);
}

int sub_one (int i) {
    return i-1;
}
int add_one (int i) {
    return i+1;
}

int foo1 (int foo2 (int),int i) {
    return foo2(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the following code, it shows how to call functions they way you wanted to call.

```
 #include <stdio.h>


/* Declaration of foo1 . It receives a specific function pointer foo2 and an integer. */
int foo1 (int (*foo2)(int), int a);

int cube(int number)
{
    return (number * number * number);
}

int square(int number)
{
    return (number * number);
}

int foo1 (int (*foo2)(int), int a)
{
    int ret;

    /* Call the foo2 function here. */
    ret = foo2(a);

    printf("Result is: %d\r\n", ret);

    return (ret);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;

    foo1(square, a);
    foo1(cube, a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A code dump is not an answer, especially if the code doesn't even contain `int foo1 (int foo2 (int a));` or address OP's question.

Comment: @melpomene Would be please remove that vote ? Only if you think it's not wrong answer. Otherwise, let it be there.